# How to connect expo react-native app on iOS device to Homestead VM?

Tags: ios, laravel, react-native, expo, homestead

I am using Laravel Homestead as a backend VM and expo to build a mobile app with react native.

I am able to make requests in the iOS Xcode simulator to http://mysite.test and I am able to make requests on an actual iOS device to http(s)://mysite.org production server.

However, I am unable to make requests from my physical iOS device to the test environment.

What I need to do:

1. **Allow requests to HTTP**.

Expo does not expose the info.plist, but I added this to the app.json file (not sure if it is correct)

```
"ios": {
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "infoPlist": {
    "NSAppTransportSecurity": {
      "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads": true
    }
  }
}
```

2. **I am not sure where to send the requests. Posting to http://mysite.test times out, and I have tried many port configurations such as homesteads 192.168.10.10:80, :8000, :8080 etc**.

I have also tried pointing to my local machine. The ipv4 is available from networking panel, and my local internet IP address, but no luck. I am lost.

Can someone help me, and others- please??